# Novel ways to gauge pressure

Tags: pressure, air, volume

I'm interested in determining the pressure of a pipe filled with compressed air with some degree of accuracy (~10% of total value~) using systems that are not just a supplied pressure gauge.

eg - one that I've thought of already, attach a balloon to a pipe outlet (with elasticity/strength proportional to estimated pressure) and roughly calculate volume change once it reaches equilibrium (balloons are perfect spheres right ;) ).

in question form, what are your oddball ideas for measuring compressed air pressure?

(I've made an effort to make this question more open ended and encouraging of creativity/shared learning than my last attempt, but let me know if it falls outside of allowed questions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Bourdon tube (basically, just a dead-end springy curved pipe which unbends
according to the internal pressure), or a tube-gears-spring mechanism
based on a Bourdon tube (i.e. a standard dial pressure gage).  I like
the idea of a spiral pipe, free end glued to a protractor-like scale, 
with a dangling weight for a pointer.

Or, use a wireless air pressure sensor.   These are part of most modern
auto wheels, often part of the valve stem, and typically operate  with either a longlife battery, or use RF excitation (like an RFID tag).   They
are intended for tire-pressure range, of course (so pressures outside the 20-100 psi range are unlikely to work with off-the-shelf units).

Or, apply (glue) some strain gages to the pipe, and watch its length
(or girth) increase as a function of internal pressure.

Or, use a zinc-air battery; the oxygen partial pressure determines the
output voltage of these cells.   You'll have to replace those, though,
from time to time, and run wires.[Zn-Air O2 sensor](http://www.nwdesigns.com/rebreathers/Nuggets/ZincAir.htm)

Or use a bit of red ruby; the red fluorescence of these stones is slightly
color-shifted as a function of applied pressure (OK, that's somewhat weird,
but I've done it).  You'll need an optical window, though.[Mao, Bell et al](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986JGR....91.4673M)

Comment: These are fantastic (especially the ruby, that would never have occurred to me). Thanks for taking the time to share!

Answer (score 1):

Compare the weight of the zero pressure pipe to the weight of the pressured pipe.